# HT16K33 alternative for common anode?

Tags: led-driver, led-matrix

I'm trying to drive a common cathode 8x8 bicolor LED matrix (1088AHG) with an HT16K33. However, the seller made a mistake and send me a **1088BHG** which is common anode. Later the seller send me a right one, but doesn't ask me to send the wrong one back (I guess the express delivery fee is too expensive that the seller doesn't want to afford it).

So I'm wondering how to make good use of the common anode one. Is there a suitable alternative of HT16K33 that also has well supported Arduino libs?

Comment: I know some chip from IS31FL37xx family would do, but they are much more expensive than HT16K33.

Comment: Well, looks like [TM1640](http://www.titanmec.com/product/display-drivers/led-panel-display-driver-chip/2022081799.html) is a good option. I'll give it a try and see if it works as expected.

Comment: With maxint's TM16xx lib, this is what I get now https://github.com/maxint-rd/TM16xx/issues/34#issuecomment-1475173424